# No Method Error in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting a weird error that I can't figure out why it is so.

Here's the related part of the controller:

```
def viewblg (num = 0, type = 0)
    if type == 1
      @blg = Compsci.find_by (num)
    else
      @blg = Personalb.find_by(num)
    end
  end
```

Here is the view where it fails:

```
    <h3><b><u>
        <%= 
            if @blg.title != nil
                @blg.title
            else
                "Error" 
            end
        %>
    </u></b></h3>
```

The exact error I get is:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT: here is a view page where I am passing variables via link_to:

```
   <ul>
    <% @compsci.each do |blog| %>
        <li><%= link_to "#{blog.title}", viewblog_path(blog.number, 1) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Also, here is the route path I have for the link_to

```
get 'pblog' =>'blog#personal'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that `@blg` is `nil`. Also, `.find_by` seems wrong. Shouldn't it be just `.find`?

If you are not trying to find by the id, you should do `.find_by_number(num)`. Or even: `.find_by(number: num)`

And after you fix it, you do this in your view:

```
<% if @blg.title.present? %>
  <%= @blg.title %>
<% else %>
  Error
<% end %>
```

Comment: doing find_by_attribute(number: num) gives me an undefined method error. I tried doing find_by(number: num) but gives me the same undefined method error. When I try find(attribute: num) or find(num) I get no errors, but then the entire view page doesn't render and am shown a blank white screen

Comment: The name of the attribute you are looking for is `number`?

Comment: go to your console `rails c`, and try `Compsci.find_by(number: num)` and also `Personalb.find_by(number: num)` see if it returns you something. Change `num` by `0` or some other number you think that should work. If it doesn't return anything there, it means that those statements aren't finding anything on your database.

Comment: Ok, what does it return when you do `Personalb.find_by(number: num).title` ?

Comment: the title of a blog post, which is currently set to "test"

Comment: So, you are doing it right by using `.find_by(number: num)` now.

Comment: yea, but everything gets defaulted to my else statement, which isnt supposed to happen, because I am supposed to have a title

Comment: I think your syntax should be right now. Are you sure that the `num` you are passing is what you think it is? Have you tried using the constant number you used in the console, on your controller instead, to see if it works?

Comment: I used 1 and 2. I didn't use num. I think it could be num, not sure how to test that though

Answer (score 0):

One of this lines `Compsci.find_by (num)` or `Personalb.find_by(num)` is returning nil. Maybe you should use just `find(num)`.

Comment: find(num) will not give any errors, but then the entire view page doesnt get rendered and am shown a blank white screen

Comment: Now you get the correct object. Maybe title is not `nil` but a blank string. You can avoid this problem using `@blg.title.present?` instead of `@blg.title != nil`.

Comment: undefined method 'title'

Comment: So `find(num)` returns nil. You have no objects in db. You need to verify with `if @blg.present? && @blg.title.present?`.

Comment: No more errors, but now i have now blog title at all, and reverts to my "else" statement (which I don't want)

Comment: Because `@blg` is nil or `@blg.title` is nil. The error was solved. You need create valid objects to see titles.

Comment: When I use find_by(number: num) in rails c, it returns the correct object though

Comment: Ok. But your example is using `find_by(num)` not `find_by(number: num)`. Your example is wrong. If you are using `find_by(number: num)` you get a collection and do `@blg.title` doesn't make sense because @blg is an array.

Comment: The example is wrong. I am now using find_by(number: num). So how can I find the object as an array?

Comment: You are getting an array of objects. You need iterate over that array. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`@blg` is nil, causing your `@blg.title` to be calling `.title` on `nil`. Make sure you are passing the correct parameters to `find_by` -- your default is `0`, which would return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `undefined method 'xxxxx' for nil:NilClass` in the view, You need to verify the @blg is not nil before you call its attributes

```
<% if @blg.present? %>
  <%= @blg.title %>
<% else %>
  Error
<% end %>
```

This is the syntax of `find_by`

```
Client.find_by first_name: 'Lifo'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by

And your action might look like this

```
def viewblg (num = 0, type = 0)
  if type == 1
    @blg = Compsci.find_by(nubmer: num)
  else
    @blg = Personalb.find_by(number: num)
  end
end
```

Comment: My action looks like yours. When I use .find_by(number: num) in rails c, it returns the correct object, how ever, with the correction to the view page it defaults to the else

Comment: I guest you get `type` and `num` from  search  parameters. if so, you might need to change type -> `params[:type]` and num -> `params[:num]`

Comment: Please update your question with `routes.rb` and` the code link` in your view.